# How to get the first value of a filtered JSONPath output

Tags: jsonpath

Below is the sample json that I used to get data based on string search using JSONPath.

```
{
    "tool":
    {
        "jsonpath":
        {
            "creator":
            {
                "name": "Jayway Inc.",
                "location":
                [
                    "Malmo",
                    "San Francisco",
                    "Helsingborg"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "book":
    [
        {
            "title": "Beginning JSON",
            "price": 49.99
        },
        {
            "title": "JSON at Work",
            "price": 59.99
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSONPath expression used is

> "$.book[?(@.price == 49.99)].title"

The response for the above JSONPath is an array with single string that is the title.

```
[
   "Beginning JSON"
]
```

Is it possible to get the output as a String instead of an array. It is ok to get the first value if it contains multiple values in the array.